# get dynamic values, sum and show the total in <span> element

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this html below where the user can select how many "registrations" wants for each registration type.

Based on this selection the span with class ".total" should show the total.

I have this html and jquery and is working fine to show the total in the  with class ". total" based on user select menu selection: https://jsfiddle.net/ev1ccmyL/. The issue is that I'm doing with static registration types "general" and "plus" and with default values.

The html with dynamic code is like below. Do you know how to change the jQuery to use the dynamic values below?

```
<div class="card_body">
  <ul>

    @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div class="w-100">
        <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
      </div>
      <form>
        <select id="{{$rtype->name}}">
          @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
          <option >{{ $i }}</option>
          @endfor
          </select>
          </form>
        <span class="font-size-sm w-50 text-right">X {{$rtype->price}}€</span>
        </li>
      @endforeach


    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
      </div>
      <span class="total">0.00€</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: does the second select '#select' also dynamically created?

Comment: Both selects are dynamic, they appear with the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your select like the folowing.

select element:

```
<select class="rtype_name" id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}" name={{ $rtype->name }}>`
```

In your js file update as follows.

```
$('body').on("change", ".rtype_name", function () { 
    var total = 0; 

    $('.rtype_name').each(function(i, obj) { 
        var value = +$(this).val(); 
        var price = $(this).data('price');
        if(value && price) { 
            total = total + (value * price); 
        } 
    }); 

    var total = total.toFixed(2)+"€" 
    $(".total").text(total); 
});
```

[Jquery code used because there is a jquery tag in question, ]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didnt explain well. Both selects are dynamic. For example there are two registration types in the db for now, general and plus. So it appears two select menus, the user can in each select menu select how many registrations want from each registration type. And based on that selection I want to show the total price. So cannot exist a select like "<select class="rtype_name" id="general_{{ $rtype->id }}">`" because there is a registration type general for this conference, yes, but can exist a registration type "rt001" or any other name.

Comment: Thanks but there is some issue. When the page is accessed there are 2 registration types for now and both registration type have the value "1" by default in the select menu. The first registration type has the price "10" the second "20" so it should appear in the .total span when the page is accessed "30.00€" but it appears "0.00€".

Comment: Then I select for the first registration type for example 2 registrations and the .total span continues to show "0.00", only after selecting a value for the second registration type, for example, "2" the .total span shows a price value.

Comment: But also this price value is incorrect, if the user selected 2 registration types of the first registration type that have price "10" and 2 registration types of the second registration type that have the price "20" the total should be "60" but in the total span it appears "40".

Comment: for the first problem trigger a change event to the class 'rtype_name' on page load.

Comment: what is the calculation logic of the price?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167435/discussion-between-ab-in-and-johnz).